# Maximum file size in email attachment PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

My application can send an email with an attachment successfully, but when the attachment exceeds 800KB the message doesn't get delivered. What could be the problem?

Comment: You haven't change the MAXFILESIZE in your php.ini

Comment: I have,What i have is upload_max_filesize = 20M

Comment: Then it could be that your mail server limits attachment size.

Comment: You need to be aware about the fact that many email providers do not allow you to exceed some max file size. This will vary on which provider do you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no limit for Email**. If you want to send 50MB+ attachment you can. It will handle by your mail sender.

Don't use Codeigniter mail. Use some other **third party Mail library**'s.

---

Some best Third party Library's which cooperate with codeigniter

1. [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
2. [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

---

As well as about  **PHP.ini** settings which you can test own

1. **memory_limit** - PHP may require more memory to import large files then it has available. Increasing this value will give PHP more
   memory to use. 60mb has proven to be a good value for this variable
   if you want to handle attachments up to about 10mb.
2. **max_execution_time** - The time PHP has to execute a script. If you're
   downloading large files from across the internet, you may need more
   time
3. **upload_max_filesize** - The maximum size a file upload can be. This
   affects files staff try to upload to attach to emails.
4. **post_max_size** - The maximum size an HTTP POST request can be, this
   can limit the maximum size a file can be when uploading files to
   attach to emails.
5. **upload_tmp_dir** - The directory uploaded files are temporarily stored
   in during transmission. If no attachments of any size are able to be
   uploaded then this value may be unset or set to a directory which is
   not writable by the web server.

Comment: Enjoy coding :)